# ansible stdout_lines formatting output

Tags: ansible, roles

the desired output is to **show the name of the target directory and its contents**.  please see below. any sample code ideas on how to accomplish this? is it doable? thank you

**role code: listing contents of directories**

```
   vars_files:
     - /home/admin/.ansible/vault/vault.yml
   
      vars:
        - target_dirs:
            - '/home/admin'
            - '/root'
  
      tasks:
        - name: disk_usage
          shell: ls -l {{ item }}
          with_items: "{{ target_dirs }}"
          register: disk_usage
          ignore_errors: true
   
        - debug:
            msg:
              - "disk usage"
              - "=========="
              - "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ disk_usage | json_query('results[].stdout_lines') }}"
```

**current output**

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => (item=['total 0']) => {
    "msg": [
        "disk usage",
        "############",
        [
            "total 0"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [server1] => (item=['total 8', 'drwx------. 2 root root 4096 May 15  2020 bin', '-rwx------. 1 root root  519 May 15  2020 clean.sh']) => {
    "msg": [
        "disk usage",
        "==========",
        [
            "total 8",
            "drwx------. 2 root root 4096 May 15  2020 bin",
            "-rwx------. 1 root root  519 May 15  2020 clean.sh"
        ]
    ]
}
```

**desired output: state the name of the target directory and its contents**

```
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": [
        "disk usage /home/admin",
        "==========",
        [
            "total 0"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": [
        "disk usage /root",
        "==========",
        [
            "total 8",
            "drwx------. 2 root root 4096 May 15  2020 bin",
            "-rwx------. 1 root root  519 May 15  2020 clean.sh"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── test1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── test2
    ├── file4
    ├── file5
    └── file6

2 directories, 6 files
```

and the variable

```yaml
    target_dirs:
      - /tmp/test/test1
      - /tmp/test/test2
```

the debug below writes the expected JSON

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          disk usage {{ item.item }}
          {{ '=' * under_line_length|int }}
          {{ item.stdout_lines|to_nice_json }}
      loop: "{{ disk_usage.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        under_line_length: "{{ item.item|length + 11 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/test1) => 
  msg: |-
    disk usage /tmp/test/test1
    ==========================
    [
        "total 0",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:09 file1",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file2",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file3"
    ]
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/test2) => 
  msg: |-
    disk usage /tmp/test/test2
    ==========================
    [
        "total 0",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file4",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file5",
        "-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file6"
    ]
```

---

- You can write YAML if you want to

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          disk usage {{ item.item }}
          {{ '=' * under_line_length|int }}
          {{ item.stdout_lines|to_nice_yaml }}
      loop: "{{ disk_usage.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        under_line_length: "{{ item.item|length + 11 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/test1) => 
  msg: |-
    disk usage /tmp/test/test1
    ==========================
    - total 0
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:09 file1
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file2
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file3
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/test2) => 
  msg: |-
    disk usage /tmp/test/test2
    ==========================
    - total 0
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file4
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file5
    - -rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Jan 25 04:10 file6
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    target_dirs:
      - /tmp/test/test1
      - /tmp/test/test2

  tasks:

    - command: "ls -l {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ target_dirs }}"
      register: disk_usage
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          disk usage {{ item.item }}
          {{ '=' * under_line_length|int }}
          {{ item.stdout_lines|to_nice_yaml }}
      loop: "{{ disk_usage.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        under_line_length: "{{ item.item|length + 11 }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          disk usage {{ item.item }}
          {{ '=' * under_line_length|int }}
          {{ item.stdout_lines|to_nice_json }}
      loop: "{{ disk_usage.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        under_line_length: "{{ item.item|length + 11 }}"
```